# Styling For src="imageUrl in Html"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, sass

How can I style images coming in from an API imageUrl? I am trying to add in some padding between the columns. The images from API come in fine but they are so close together on a medium to small there is no spacing at all, screen seems fine for mobile.  I tried bootstrap 4.3 img-fluid but it makes the images very small.

small snippet

```
       <div class="container"  >
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <div class="col-4" style="padding-right: 20px">   
              <img   [src]="x.imageUrl"   alt="images"/>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

I guess I need to know if its possible before I continue down this avenue.

Thanking You in Advance

PH

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. Either apply styles using Angular best practice, or apply a style class. What's the specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class in your image tag or style every image in CSS with the `img` selector.

Your CSS code may look like this:

```css
img {
  padding: 30px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Try it on: https://jsfiddle.net/braganca/y0umpfwn/7/

Found a playground for Angular here you can see how to replicate it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ww1eqs?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case this wouldn't work for me, my images are coming from an api therefore there is only one image tag. I develop for responsiveness as well. I have added some things that work for me using bootstrap and simple CSS3 styling for the layout I thought I would share.
The styling is inline for testing purposes, I will add it in a class in a style sheet.  On thing to note is that I did override the bootstrap img-fluid class in my style sheet in order for this to work.

```
.img-fluid{
 max-height: 100%;
 }
```

This is just a small snippet of the code. Which works for me.

```
<div class="container" style="height:100%; width:300px;">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
   <div class="col-6">
    <img class="img-fluid" [src]="someinputproperty.imageUrl" 
    alt="clothing"/>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```